# Update 2nd Level Cache instead of Invalidating

Tags: hibernate, hazelcast

We are using Hibernate 3.5.6 together with Hazelcast 3.6.1 as a 2nd level cache. We have the following problem. We have an Hibernate entity with a non-lazy collection. When adding elements to the collection in two consecutive sessions on the same node, the whole collection is always reloaded from the database. I would have expected that the 2nd level cache could just be updated when an element is added to the collection instead of completely evicting it from the cache and reloading it each time to add another entry. Is this a principle problem of the Hibernate 2nd level cache, or is this a configuration issue on our side?

Comment: This can be related to capacity of the cache. Have you checked that?

Comment: <hazelcast>
  <map name="default">
    ...
    <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">5000</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <min-eviction-check-millis>100</min-eviction-check-millis>
    ...
  </map>
</hazelcast>

Comment: I changed the configuration accordingly, but it didn't change the behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can answer the question myself. In fact Hibernate will *not* update the collection, but always invalidate it. I found the following explanation here: http://planet.jboss.org/post/collection_caching_in_the_hibernate_second_level_cache:

> What are the caching semantics? Well, the key one is that collections are never updated in the cache; they are only invalidated out of the cache and then potentially cached again later as the result of another database read. So, if an application called Group.addMember(), Hibernate will remove that group’s membership collection from the cache. If JBoss Cache is the second level cache implementation, that removal will be propagated around the cluster; the collection will be removed from the cache on all nodes in the cluster.
>
> If later the application needs to access the members from that group, another database read will occur and the current set of primary keys for the members will be put into the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The hibernate cache, by default is keyed on PK, so when you do a findAll(), it will not use the hibernate cache, when you do a findOne(id) it will.

If you want to cache findAll() I would use ehcache and @Cache annoations, be careful on what key it uses for it's cache.  See http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/get-started/key-classes-methods.html

Comment: The problem we have is that we want to add an element to the collection. Hibernate will always load the whole collection in order to add an element to it. The problem is now that if the collection cannot be loaded from the 2nd level cache (which I don't understand in our case) it will always query the database to load the whole collection.

Comment: @JanSchaefer correct you will have to role this cache yourself.  I'm happy to be proved wrong, but I have been through the exact same problem as you many times.